# SSRS Pass multiple parameters by clicking on grouping cell in Tablix

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, parameter-passing, ssrs-tablix

I've got a tablix in a report like the following:

```
Case  Owner    Contract
  1   Dario      123
  1   Mario      456
  2   Giorgio    789
  2   Carla      910
```

By clicking on any cell of column Case I want to pass all the parameters associated for column Owner.
For example if you clicked 1 the tablix should pass: Dario and Mario.

Comment: You want to pass the values - to what? If you mean a linked drill-through report: Just pass the number (`Case`) and let the query of the second report determine the names.

Comment: Hi Wolfang, yes it was a drill through. However, I've solved it by concatenating the cases ans splitting the concatenated names in an expression.